# Facebook api /me/likes/page-id does not work if page-id is not a number

Tags: facebook-graph-api

In Facebook there are pages that have page-id as number 
For example the CocaCola page

```
https://www.facebook.com/40796308305
```

If I do

```
FB.api('/me/likes/40796308305)
```

it works OK and I get the data in `response.data`

but if I do

```
FB.api('/me/likes/cocacola)
```

it does not work and I get

```
response.error="(#100) cannot connect...
```

Is there a way to convert the name to a number or make this work with names?

Comment: you have `FB.api('/me/likes/cocacola)` which looks like you're missing a `'` before the closing `)`

Answer (score 3):

You can get the ID of the page from the Graph API by just calling `http://graph.facebook.com/cocacola`  this will return the complete object for the page which also contains the page id as a numeric value

Comment: What do you mean 'call'? how do I call and how do I get the result?

Comment: You're welcome ;-) Please also accept the right answer when asking a question here ;-)